# Why TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() is not showing the correct hour offset with UTC in non daylight saving dates?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get the number of hours difference between the time zones and UTC. I changed my machine's date to some date in July so that I am outside of daylight considerations and ran the two code segments below. One in LinqPad and one in SSMS. I am in Pacific time. Why is TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() always reporting -8 whether current time is daylight saving or not, while SQL Server is reporting -7 or -8 depending on daylight savings?

Is there a way to make TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() display the actual hour offsets or is it fixed? I didn't see a parameter for this.

**C#:**

```
TimeZoneInfo local = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var tzi in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    sb.AppendFormat(" {0}| {1} | {2} | {3} | {4}",

                    tzi.BaseUtcOffset.TotalHours,
                    tzi.StandardName,
                    tzi.DisplayName,
                    tzi.DaylightName,
                    tzi.SupportsDaylightSavingTime);
    sb.AppendLine();
}

string table = sb.ToString().Dump(); // Always -8 for Pacific. Why?
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh,GETUTCDATE(),GETDATE())  -- -7 o -8. This is expected
```

Comment: did u find out how to take the time WITH DTS using GetSystemTimeZones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking the **BaseUtcOffset** which is the time for the zone **without** DST adjustments.

Comment: How i take the time WITH DTS using GetSystemTimeZones?

Comment: @D.B GetSystemTimeZones always gets the zone without the offset, could this be what your looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.local?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_TimeZoneInfo_Local